# 3000-lumen LED flood light with low-voltage landscape lighting?

Tags: landscaping

Is it possible to find a 3000-lumen LED flood light that uses low voltage? ...or is that outside the possibility of low voltage?

Comment: Check battery powered led spotlights.

Comment: Utterly possible. I don't happen to know of one, because I haven't been shopping for that sort of thing recently. But if you're going to make this a shopping question, it's probably going to get closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few minutes of searching (*and ignoring bad results - line voltage ones get in there, thank search result polluters*) for **12V 3000 lumen flood** shows many options, some as high as 9000 or 18000 lumens. Closest I've found to *exactly* 3000 was 3120 lumens, but I'm not trying to buy the thing, and I'm not shopping for you. I would not consider it a deal breaker to have 120 lumens extra. 2800 is also common.

It's certainly "possible" as you ask.

Comment: Thanks. I spent more than a few minutes and didn't find anything that wasn't line voltage. I'll have to try again. It doesn't have to be 3,000 lumen exactly. I was just looking for something more than 1,000 or 1,100.

Comment: I tried again using your search terms and immediately found what I was looking for.

Example:
https://www.amazon.com/Outdoor-Security-Floodlight-Outside-Waterproof/dp/B07W3L462Z